# creating a static route and a default gateway

Tags: networking, gateway

Im having troubles with my routing table, im getting `RTNETLINK answers: file exist`

How do i set my default gateway (internet) to 192.168.100.1? and a static route going to 10.169.5.0 /26?

i have 2 GW as shown in flags, how do i remove the `G` on my route line # 2?

```
Destination    Gateway          Genmask         Flags    Metric    Ref   Use    Iface
0.0.0.0        192.168.100.1     0.0.0.0         UG       100      0      0      eth0
10.169.5.0     10.169.5.1     255.255.255.192    UG        0       0      0      eth1
192.168.5.0     0.0.0.0       255.255.255.0      U         0       0      0      eth2
```

Comment: Why do you need to remove the `G`? The `G` means gateway, it doesn't mean that it's a default route. The `G` has to be there if you are adding a route for the network `10.169.5.0/26`, because the packets will go through a "gateway". The `Destination 0.0.0.0` is what denotes that it's a default route, which is your first line. So your routing table is currently configured correctly according to your question: `How do I set my default gateway (internet) to 192.168.100.1? and a static route going to 10.169.5.0 /26?` When and where do you get the error `RTNETLINK answers: file exist`?

Comment: `10.169.5.1` is a gateway to other network as well, it conflicts with my `192.168.100.1` how can i tell the system to route everything to `192.169.5.1` when dealing with `10.169.5.0` destinations?

Comment: i managed to answer my question by issuing this command:
`route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.169.5.1`

Comment: Hmm, that's strange, because the settings in your question should achieve what you wanted in your first comment. The command you issued is now routing all the 10.0.0.0/8 network to 10.169.5.1, not just 10.169.5.0/26. Anyways, you got it fixed! You should answer your own question and accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for some strange reasons, playing with my routing table, i managed to make it work by issuing this route

`route add -net 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.0.0.0 gw 10.169.5.1`

Comment: This is not permanent though